# Does Pivotal projectmonitor require Xcode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, macos, teamcity-9.0, pivotaltracker

My iMac(Mac OS Sierra V10.12) doesn't have Xcode. so I get below error during 'bundle install'. When I tried to install Xcode from AppStore, I realized it's of size 4 GB. SO just wanted to ensure I am not doing something wrong.

current directory:
/Users/xecckq4/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1
/Users/xecckq4/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20170813-3495-gf683v.rb extconf.rb
**Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license**
agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.

*** extconf.rb failed ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`extconf.rb`](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/) configures the makefile that specifies all the things you'll need to build a gem. In your case, XCode is required, so yes, by all means, download and install it.

If you're on a Mac, you're probably going to be making use of Homebrew as well, which also depends on XCode (as do a number of other gems you'll run into sooner or later), so even if decided to ignore this issue, you'd need XCode sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks, Bud. It worked.

I installed Xcode after which bundle install went smoothly. Yes, I am on a mac.